# Excel sheet auto-formatting category Id's to number format

Tags: excel, magento

I am having trouble displaying category ID's in my excel sheet.
I am trying to separate category Id's for importing my products into my Magento store, but as soon as I insert something like this "3,294,297" it autoformats it as being a number (displaying it as "3294297"), but infact the 3 numbers are category Id's which I have separated by comma for importing purposes.

I have looked through my excel settings & also tried finding a solution online with no success.

How would I go about removing the autoformatting?

Comment: ***My Answer:***

In Excel 2007, click "Home" tab on the top menu & navigate to the "number" section. Click the dropdown box & select "text" format" which is located down the very bottom of the dropdown menu (may require you to scroll).

Hopefully this helps anyone else who missed the location of the text area :).

Comment: you should post your answer as an answer not just as a comment, that way other people will be able to see it easier.

Comment: Unfortunately you need over 200 rep to answer your own question, or wait 7 hours after submitting the question. It mentioned I should insert a comment instead.

Comment: @EfficientTradeLtd: Then you should wait seven hours. That mechanism is there for a reason, and the reason is _not_ to encourage you to break the site by writing answers as comments instead.

Comment: Yes I shall write in my diary the times I can answer my own questions and waste peoples time for 7 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the formatting style of the cell to text, you can do this by right clicking and selecting formatting, or simply starting the list of numbers with a ' will make excel treat it as a string (text)

Comment: oh duh, I had to scroll down a tiny bit further on the format section at the top of the excel menu. I couldn't see the text option at first & kept changing it to "general" format, which would then keep changing back to "number format as soon as I re-inserted the ID's. Sorry for wasting you time....my own error.